# UITableView inside of UIScrollView or using TableView Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I guess this question is more of a best practice question than a problem solving question.

I would like to have a page on my app that has a `UITableView` at the bottom of it and some buttons/text above the `UITableView` but instead of just the `UITableView` scrolling, I would like the whole page to scroll.

I have been searching around and some people say to put the `UITableView` inside of a `UIScrollView` and disable scrolling on it and recalculate the height so the table view is as tall as all of it's rows.

Then I have read some other people say just to put the buttons/text in a Table Row Header and just have that scroll with the whole table view.

Which is the better practice and are either of them frowned upon?

Thanks!

Comment: 'Best practice' questions usually turn out to be a nasty can of worms... specially since you know that some people believe in one practice and some in the other..

Comment: Ya, I was just wondering if there was a better way to do it, but I guess its very subjective.  I think I am just going to do it by making a Table View Header instead.

Answer (score 0):

Open the main storyboard and on the bottom right hand side you should see a list of view controllers, buttons, gestures etc.. In that list there should be a controller called "page control" that opts for the page-scroll you are looking for as well as the continuous one which you are trying to get rid of, you can just insertt this in to your basic view controller (via drag and drop). As for the button responsible for the segue (turning the page) you can find that in the list too. I can't explain how to program the button to turn the page step by step as I am typing this on my phone at work right now. If you want I can edit this later in more detail